# Using string.format with "{" already in string python

Tags: python, string

The string already has `'{'` inside it. Now I want to use python format method.

```
a = "{foo{}}"
b = a.format("bar")
```

result should be `{foobar}`

There are many ways to solve the problem but I want to know is there a way to skip first `'{'`.

Comment: In Python=>3.6 you can use f-strings and just like in `format` you use double braces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To have a regular brace, use it twice in a format string.

```
>>> "{{foo{}}}".format("bar")
'{foobar}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the %x syntax as well:

```
a = "{foo%s}"
b = a % 'bar'
```

Which will return `'{foobar}'` just fine.

FYI: to print % in a string you would use `%%`.